# Prove or give a counterexample: If $f,g$ are continuous and proper, then the product $fg$ is proper.

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

A function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow  \mathbb R$ is called proper if $f^{-1}(C)$ is compact for every compact set C.
Prove or give a counterexample: If $f,g$ are continuous and proper, then the product $fg$ is proper.

My attempt: Let $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ and product of two continuous function is continuous. This implies $h(x)$ is continuous.

Now, I claim that $h(x)$ is proper by showing that $f^{-1}(C)$ has finite number of subcovers.

Is this idea is correct? If not can anyone suggest the contradict example?

Comment: You haven't provided any proof though.

Comment: I mean this idea.

Comment: Huh, that's weird, I definitely didn't type "Does this answer your question?" Does it automatically comment something like that when you vote to close as a duplicate?